# xmlstarlet: how to add element, using value of existing one

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

starting from

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>a feed</title>
    <link>https://afeed</link>
    <description>lorem ipsum</description>
    <item>
      <title>lorem ipsum</title>
      <description>lorem ipsum des</description>
      <pubDate>Sat, 23 Feb 2019 10:50:00 GMT</pubDate>
      <dc:date>2019-02-23T10:50:00Z</dc:date>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>lorem ipsum sit</title>
      <description>lorem ipsum sit des</description>
      <pubDate>Sat, 23 Feb 2019 10:49:00 GMT</pubDate>
      <dc:date>2019-02-23T10:49:00Z</dc:date>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

I'm able to add an element using

```
xmlstarlet edit --omit-decl \
    --subnode '//item' --type elem --name myelement --value myvalue \
input.xml
```

But how to use as value element the value of another element? 
Using in example

```
xmlstarlet edit --omit-decl \
    --subnode '//item' --type elem --name myelement --value //item/pubDate \
input.xml
```

I have `//item/pubDate` as value, but I would like to insert `//item/pubDate` value for every item.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an empty subnode and then create its content with `--update` and a relative path. `--update` has the possibility to use an xpath with `--expr`.

```
xmlstarlet edit --omit-decl \
  --subnode '//item' --type elem --name myelement \
  --update  '//item/myelement' --expr '../pubDate/text()' input.xml
```

---

See: `xmlstarlet edit`